# Translating own OSM server tile to English (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, ubuntu, osm2pgsql

I have created a OSM tile server using the https://switch2osm.github.io/ tutorial for ubuntu 18.04 with great success but no matter what I cannot display the map labels in English only, I have tried many solutions from the OpenStreetMap help forum but none seem to work for me.

I tried adding the line `node,way name:en text linear` to the default.style in osm2pgsql so the field name:en gets included in the postgres database, but the name:en field never appears on the tables even re-building osm2pgsql, dropping the current table and re loading the map data into db did not help(I am using https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/azerbaijan-latest.osm.pbf from the switch2osm guide).

Can you guide me?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may encounter the same issue, there are some places you may want to look at.

1. Just copy the `node,way name:en text linear` line in the style file, if you try with tab or input an incorrect number spaces osm2pgsql may not recognize that line.
2. Make sure the import command is pointing at the right file: I was using this command `osm2pgsql -d gis --create --slim  -G --hstore --tag-transform-script ~/src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.lua -C 2500 --number-processes 1 -S ~/src/openstreetmap-carto/openstreetmap-carto.style ~/data/azerbaijan-latest.osm.pbf` but making the changes in a different style file.

So a combination of those two was giving me a headache.